# How to sign data using p12 file in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, digital-signature, security-framework

For a web service request in iOS, I need to sign one of the POST parameters using a .p12 file that I have. Following is the method I adopted:

1. I imported the .p12 file into the XCode Project.
2. I loaded the data of the .p12 file into an `NSData` object.
3. I checked Security Framework documentation and found a method called [SecKeyRawSign](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000157-CH1g-SW26) that creates a digital signature from raw data.
4. But, the parameters of this method confuse me. I am supposed to pass a `SecKeyRef key` parameter to this method. But, all I have is the `NSData` object (containing the data from the .p12 file)

How do I get the variable of type `SecKeyRef` from the .p12 file?

Or basically, how do I sign data using just a .p12 file in Objective-C?

Comment: .p12 contains X.509 certificates, optionally with corresponding private keys. The obvious path is using PKCS#7 signing of the data (either wrapping or detached).

Comment: Well, my question is how do you do it in Objective-C? :)

Comment: we do it with our SecureBlackbox library ;). I don't know how they do it with built-in libraries (if this is avaialble at all).

Comment: were you able to implement this ? , please post your code if you did.